# C# memory usage: value vs reference type for stream class usage in Team Foundation Server dlls

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, tfs, stream, memorystream

I am following the example here ([How to attach a file to work item in TFS without physical file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759153/how-to-attach-a-file-to-work-item-in-tfs-without-physical-file-path)) to attach a file to a work item in TFS, by having a stream instead of having a physical file. I have the following code:

```
internal static void AddAttachment(WorkItemServer server, Project teamProject, string fileContent, WorkItem workItem)
{
    FileAttachment attachment = new FileAttachment();
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(fileContent);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            attachment.LocalFile = stream;
            attachment.AreaNodeUri = "";
            attachment.FileNameGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
            attachment.ProjectUri = teamProject.Uri.ToString();

            server.UploadFile(attachment);

            const string c_UpdatePackage = @"<validxml>";
            XmlDocument updatePackage = new XmlDocument();
            updatePackage.LoadXml(string.Format(c_UpdatePackage, workItem.Id /*work item ID*/, workItem.Rev /*work item latest revision*/, "Test attachment", attachment.FileNameGUID, DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'"), fileContent.Length, "John Smith", "http://localhost:8080/tfs/defaultcollection"));

            XmlElement outputPackage;
            string dbStamp;
            IMetadataRowSets metadata;
            server.Update(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), updatePackage.DocumentElement, out outputPackage, null, out dbStamp, out metadata);
        }
    }
}
```

My question: During the assignment

```
attachment.LocalFile = stream;
```

Is stream copied to attachment.LocalFile by reference or by value? If it is copied by reference, I think the above code will not have a memory leak since it is disposing the stream in using:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) { ... }
```

But if it copied by value(a copy of stream is made), this would leave a memory leak since FileAttachment is not being disposed, right? If memory leak is present, I think it is not possible to fix this memory leak since FileAttachment is not inheriting IDisposable. Below is the decompiled code resharper shows for FileAttachment:

```
namespace Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy
{
    public struct FileAttachment
    {
        private Stream m_localFile;
        ...
        public Stream LocalFile
        {
            get
            {
                return this.m_localFile;
            }
            set
            {
                this.m_localFile = value;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

How can we confirm whether the stream object is being copied by reference or by value? If it is copied by value, how can we stop the memory leak?

Comment: Objects are always copied by reference.  Primitive types are copied by value. That's how you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object is a reference type if it is a `class`, and a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) if it is a `struct` or `enumerable`. [FileAttachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.fileattachment%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) is a `class`.

As such, the assignment `attachment.LocalFile = stream;` does not result in a memory leak because it is a copy by reference assignment.

It should also be noted that the `attachment.LocalFile` property, once it exits that `using()` scope, will point to invalid data, and will throw an exception if anything attempts to access that property.

Comment: I verified that the stream is not readable once I exit the `using()` scope. But just one issue. You mentioned in your answer that FileAttachment is a `class`. But actually it is a `struct`. Does this change the behavior of `FileAttachment.LocalFile`?

Comment: I'm guessing you are rolling your own FileAttachment class? W/r/t it being a struct, it shouldn't change anything. A reference type contained within a struct will behave as any reference type usually does. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/945708/6137718 . Mutable fields within a struct is usually considered bad practice, though.

Comment: The FileAttachment class is coming from Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy dll.